# AEM 6.3, wcm.io: sling MockResource null in @Activate method

Tags: mocking, osgi, adobe, aem, sling

I have an OSGI service that has an @Activate method. In the activate method I call a method called 'buildTitleList' where I query some resources (pages) and gather their titles in a list. This code is working in a running environment but not in my unit tests.

I create the page in my context the following way:

```
aemContext.create().page("/content/test-page', "/apps/platform-company/templates/home-page", "test-tile");
```

If I debug my unit test I can see that the resources I query in the 'buildTitleList' are empty (note: I am sure that my path is correct)

When I call the 'buildTitleList' directly in my unit test it DOES work. Is this normal behaviour, is there a way to make sure the @Activate method also can see the newly created page in the context?

Test:

```
@Test
public void checkTitles() {
    TitleService titleService = context.getService(TitleService.class);
    System.out.println(); //If I set a breakpoint here and look into the TitleService instance the list of titles is still 0
}
```

TitleService:

```
public class TitleService {

    private List<String> titles;

    public TitleService() {
        this.titles = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    }

    ...
    public void buildTitleList() throws RepositoryException, LoginException, WCMException {

        // Gather title code here (incl. newlist). This works on a running instance but the resoure is always null when calle from within an @Activa method

        this.titles.addAll(newlist);

    }
    ...

    @Activate
    protected void Activate() {
        buildTitleList();       
    }
}
```

Setup code:

```
...

public static AemContext getAemContext(RunMode runMode) {
    if (aemContext != null) {
        aemContext.runMode(runMode.getValue());
        return aemContext;
    } else {
        aemContext = newAemContext();
        aemContext.runMode(runMode.getValue());
        return aemContext;
    }
}

public static AemContext newAemContext() {
    return new AemContextBuilder()
            .resourceResolverType(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK)
            .afterSetUp(SETUP_CALLBACK)
            .build();
}

private static final AemContextCallback SETUP_CALLBACK = aemContext -> {

    // context path strategy
    MockCAConfig.contextPathStrategyRootTemplate(aemContext, Template.HOME_PAGE.getValue());

    // register sling models
    ...

    aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory());
    aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new TitleService());

    createBlueprintPages(aemContext);

    TestInformation testInformation = TestInformation.getInstance();

    for (TestLiveCopyInformation info : testInformation.getLiveCopyInformationList()) {
        aemContext.load().json(info.getResourcePath(), info.getContentRoot() + "/" + info.getLanguage().getIsoCode());
    }

    // set default current page
    aemContext.currentPage(CONTENT_ROOT);

};

...
```

Rule in test:

```
@Rule
public final AemContext context = AppAemContext.getAemContext(RunMode.AUTHOR);
```

Comment: Can you please post more of your tests code? At least your setup method and the test method.

Comment: @Jens Code has been added.

Comment: Did you register and activate your `TitleService` (see `context.registerInjectActivateService`)? For example in the `@Before` method?

Comment: I did: aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new TitleService());

Comment: Can you please add more code? Your `@Before` methods or any other setup methods you are using in your tests etc.

Comment: @Jens I just did :)

Comment: Please do not register your own `(Autoclosable)ResourceResolverFactory`. The AEM context already has it's own RRF which it uses for example if you call `aemContext.create().page()`. But your own service might be bound to the other RRF you additionally registered. You basically have to RRF which probably have their own "view" on the mock JCR which means that adding a node to one of them does not make it available for the other.

Comment: If I do not register it in the context I get the following error: Unable to inject mandatory reference 'autoClosableResourceResolverFactory' for class TitleService. How can I prevent this error from throwing but still use the RRF provided by WCM IO?

Comment: Is there a reason you are referencing `AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory` (this is your own implementation, isn't it)? Why is your service not using the normal `ResourceResolverFactory`? If you still need to use the ACRRF you might need to create a mock ACRRF that uses the aem context resource resolver. Otherwise you won't be able to use most of the resource related APIs that wcm.io provides.

Comment: Yes this is our custom implementation that implements the AutoCloseable interface. So we can use it in a try block and it will close automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165953/discussion-between-jens-and-jdruwe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jens I found out that ResourceResolver now implement the AutoClosable interface (since 6.2, we are using 6.3.1.2) so I could remove our custom factory and use the default ResourceResolverFactory, everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `buildTitleList` or `Activate` (new Java coding conventions?) since "OSGI declarative service annotations" are of no use in unit tests. You simply have no container to call the methods.

Comment: WCM IO provides support for OSGI R6 and its activate method. I can also see the activate method getting called when in debug mode.